# Select all records after a certain column condition is true in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given the following table structure

```
CustomerID | Balance | Date
      1    |  100.00 | 07-09-2016
      1    |  -50.00 | 08-09-2016
      1    |  -60.00 | 09-09-2016
      1    |  500.00 | 10-09-2016
      1    |  600.00 | 11-09-2016
      1    | -100.00 | 12-09-2016
      1    | -200.00 | 13-09-2016
      1    | -400.00 | 14-09-2016
      1    | -500.00 | 15-09-2016
```

I want to start from bottom and select all rows that has negative balance and stop once credit balance is found. For above example data, I want result to be as below

```
      1    | -100.00 | 12-09-2016
      1    | -200.00 | 13-09-2016
      1    | -400.00 | 14-09-2016
      1    | -500.00 | 15-09-2016
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086561/how-to-select-all-records-after-a-certain-column-condition-is-true-in-sql? Same user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is to use `NO EXISTS`. Return a row if no other row with a later date has a positive balance:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select * from tablename t2
                  where t2.Balance > 0
                    and t2.date > t1.date)
```

Or, let the sub-query return latest date with a balance > 0:

```
select *
from tablename
where date > (select max(date) from tablename where balance > 0)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for quick reply.